# Limitations on protected by copyright font usage for commercial targets

Tags: copyright

I want to use the "`Arphic PRond-Gothic`" font for my commercial web-site.
Because it was initially installed on my computer (or it was installed with certain soft automatically, anyway I did't bought this font), I can to reason that it is not requiring payment font. If check the font file info, it reads "`Copyright 1994-1999. Arphic Technologies`".

Is it legal to use this font on my commercial web-site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowed to ask browsers to render text in the font. But, if their computer doesn't have that font installed, the browser will not be able to.

See [the CSS specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop) for how this works.

However, you are not allowed to *distribute* the font, as that would be considered reproduction, and a copyright violation.

Answer (score 1):

As Dawn said correctly, the first hurdle you have to skip is technical and not legal: It's not a trivial matter to make the computers of other people use a font for your website that they most likely don't have.

You are not allowed to distribute the font *if you don't have a license that allows it*. Licenses for many fonts are not *that* expensive. If you cannot find any license, then it is foolish to assume that you have a license, and if you make that foolish assumption and then get sued for copyright infringement, a judge will not be happy if you tell him or her that you assumed you could just use the font.

Comment: Thanks, understood the law part. It's no problem if the visitor of website has not got the rear font: CSS engine allows easily to set substitudes if unable to display the rear font.